# How to drop a marker on the map if a circle has been drawn there

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I'm able to drop markers on the map in the click eventhandler.  But if a circle has already been drawn on the map where the user wants to put a marker, it doesn't work.  I assume the circle is "swallowing" the click and not passing it through to the map beneath. How to fix that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you draw the circle, set `clickable: false` in the circle options, and then clicks will go through to the underlying map. For example:

```
new google.maps.Circle({
    clickable: false,  // let clicks go through to the map
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.8,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.35,
    map: map,
    center: new google.maps.LatLng( 0, 0 );
    radius: 1000
});
```

Or add a click listener to the circle to create markers over it.